Grafana solo me muestra 1 hora de Logs
Tengo varios contenedores configurados para enviar los logs via Loki hacia grafana, pero solo logro visualizar dentro de Grafana la ultima hora de los logs :'(, no entiendo porque.
Esta es la configuracion que coloco en el docker-compose de cada uno de mis contenedores:
logging:
  driver: loki
  options:
    loki-url: "http://logs.miweb.com:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
    max-size: "5m"

Levanto mis contenedores y veo que en Grafana van registrandose, me voy a la parte de EXPLORE, selecciono el nombre contenedor y visualizo los logs sin problema, pero si quiero ver los de el dia anterior o asi, simplemente no me los muestra, me sige poniendo los de la ultima hora.
El archivo loki-coinfig.yaml
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 1h       # Any chunk not receiving new logs in this time will be flushed
  max_chunk_age: 1h           # All chunks will be flushed when they hit this age, default is 1h
  chunk_target_size: 1048576  # Loki will attempt to build chunks up to 1.5MB, flushing first if chunk_idle_period or max_chunk_age is reached first
  chunk_retain_period: 30s    # Must be greater than index read cache TTL if using an index cache (Default index read cache TTL is 5m)
  max_transfer_retries: 0     # Chunk transfers disabled

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /loki/boltdb-shipper-active
    cache_location: /loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
    cache_ttl: 24h         # Can be increased for faster performance over longer query periods, uses more disk space
    shared_store: filesystem
  filesystem:
    directory: /loki/chunks

compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
  shared_store: filesystem

limits_config:
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h


chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 720h

ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /loki/rules
  rule_path: /loki/rules-temp
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true

Porque? que y por donde debo indagar?
